# Why is visual studio showing error: type name not allowed, when using void as parameter for a function all?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a class with the following public method in my .hpp file:

```
virtual void finalize( void );
```

I then go on to call said function:

```
finalize( void );
```

I am required by my company's standards to put the void placeholder in. When I build this in VS 2010 I get

```
Error   11  error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ')'
```

and the tooltip on hover of the void, which is red underlined, says:

> Error: type name is not allowed

I've tried looking this up but haven't found a solution. This seems like it should be simple and I want to say my past code never had a problem before.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You *can't* put a type in there when calling it. The standard says to include it in the declaration.

Comment: Note that a parameter list of `(void)` is not necessary in C++, since it's entirely equivalent to the empty parameter list `()`.  The only reason it should be used in C++ code is if you have header files that must be compatible with C code, since in C it does make an important difference whether you use `(void)` or `()`.  But since `virtual` methods can never be used in C code, there's clearly no need for it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your companies standards, your declaration is correct, using `void` as a type.

However, when you *call it*, you cannot just pass `void` as a type.  You should just call it thusly:

```
finalize();
```